# Will a rectifier based on air gap and flexible foil work?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electricity

[image]
[image]

The white line is a flexible conducting foil suspended on the metal wire. I think the external DC circuit will induce a charge on the flexible part and the other charges move to ground. The charged flexible part will incline towards the oppositely charged electrode from the AC circuit and once the voltage reaches peak, the air breaks down and the charge is transferred. When the current switches, the flexible part moves towards the other electrode and a spark transfers the charge in the same direction as before.

Am I hideously mistaken?